# Re-Constructing a query for a CREATE VIEW without using subqueries?

Tags: mysql

My Query works fine when I run it on the Database but once I attempt to create a view I get hit with (ERROR 1349 (HY000): View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause). I have read some other posts and the problem seems to I cant write subqueries within the view on the current DB version. How would I restructure the query below to accomplish the same end goal:

```
CREATE VIEW vHW2_3_mmirkovi as (
SELECT n.Name, sum(n.profit) AS profit

FROM (SELECT v.Name, (p.sell_Price - p.cost) AS profit FROM dreamhome.A_Vendors AS v
    
INNER JOIN dreamhome.A_Products AS p ON v.V_Id = p.V_Id) AS n GROUP BY n.name ;)
```

The query without the create view statement yields

```
+--------+--------+
| Name   | profit |
+--------+--------+
| Austin |     10 |
| Grant  |     50 |
| James  |    290 |
| Wendy  |     10 |
+--------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Note that queries against VIEWs in MySQL cannot use underlying indexes, rendering their usefulness questionable

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE VIEW vHW2_3_mmirkovi AS
SELECT v.Name, 
       SUM(p.sell_Price - p.cost) AS profit 
FROM dreamhome.A_Vendors AS v
INNER JOIN dreamhome.A_Products AS p ON v.V_Id = p.V_Id
GROUP BY v.name;
```